# Is it necessary to have 143 port enabled to use the 993 port for an IMAP(SSL) connection?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, dovecot, imap

I have an email server running with Dovecot, and while trying to manage my email with Thunderbird I'm getting a weird error:

If I enable the port `143`, and `993`, Thunderbird works fine (either using `143` or `993`).

But when I disable `143` (To always force SSL), Thunderbird can not establish a connection.

I first tough that the SSL settings or certificate could be wrong, but I checked them by using the command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect imap.foo.com:993 -crlf` and everything seems to be alright.

Is it then necessary to have `143` port enabled to use the `993` for an SSL IMAP connection? Is it for being capable of establishing the first contact?

Comment: Dovecot will do STARTTLS over 143 if the client supports it.  You probably shouldn't disable this port.  Put `disable_plaintext_auth=yes` and `ssl=required` in your config.

Comment: See http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL

Comment: @Zoredache The link moved to here: https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/ssl/

Answer (score 2):

No, That's maybe because your configuration is not setup correctly to handle all mail communications on IMAPS(993) port.

On the dovecot main configuration file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` find and check for `protocols =` value and make sure it contains `imaps`. My configuration setup there seems like this:

```
...  
#protocols = imap imaps pop3 lmtp
protocols = imaps lmtp
...
```

Also you should allow port 993 on `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` file.
here is sample configs which working fine on my mail server:

```
...
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    #port = 143 => put 0 to disable imap port
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
...
}
...
```

Then you should be able to block imap 143 port in firewall.

Answer (score 1):

the alteration to `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` is no longer valid

```
protocols = imaps lmtp
```

the service failing with an error

*'imaps' protocol can no longer be specified...*

however setting `port = 0` in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` is still valid to disable non-ssl connections for dovecot.